# How to count the elements in a "cell" with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new colunm in a df that returns number of elements of a column row by row.

I tried this

`df['Elements'] = len(df['Goals'])` sadly all I get is column full of the same number, I understand what is returning are not the elements that the columns 'Goals' has in every row but all the elements included in the column 'Goals' in total. I do not know how to get the len() of the list included in the row.

Could someone help me, I would really appreciate it

Comment: You are returning the length of the entire column. Pandas methods go *AFTER* the column unless `pd` is at the beginning. Try: `df['Elements'] = df['Goals'].map(len)`? I believe `str.len` and `apply(len)` all also work.

Comment: Thanks a lot both solutions work for what I needed, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `str.len()`:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

```
df['Elements'] = df['Goals'].str.len()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! that is exactly what I was aming for

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`pandas.Dataframe.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Elements'] = df['Goals'].apply(len)
```